# How to share same variable between imported modules

Tags: python

There are two Python scripts: `master.py` and `to_be_imported.py`

Here is the `master.py`:

```
import os
os.foo = 12345
import to_be_imported
```

And here is the to_be_imported.py:

```
import os    
if hasattr(os, 'foo'):
    print 'os hasattr foo: %s'%os.foo
```

Now when I run `master.py` I get this:

```
os hasattr foo: 12345
```

indicating that the imported module `to_be_imported.py` picks up the variable declared inside the process that imported it (`master.py`).

While it works fine I would like to know why it works and also to make sure it is a safe practice.

Comment: `os.foo = 12345` - messing with other modules' attributes like that is a really bad idea.

Comment: Please clarify using real facts why it would be a bad idea.

Comment: Is there other "better" way of doing it?

Comment: the module might have a variable of the same name which it might be heavily dependent on. If you change it then you may fall into unexpected behavior

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is a bad idea per se, but you must remember few things:

1. Modules are objects in Python. **They are loaded only once and added to** `sys.modules`. These objects can also be added attributes like regular objects (with no messy implementation of `setattr`).
2. Since they are objects, but not instantiable ones, you must consider them as singletons (they **are** singletons, after all), and you must consider the disadvantages and benefits of such model:

   a. Singletons are only one object. Are you sure that accessing their attributes is concurrency-safe?
      b. Modules are global objects. Are you sure you can track the whole behavior and access to their members? Are you sure you will be able to debug errors there?
3. Is the code something you will work with others?

While no idea is better than other, good practices tell us that using global variables is not well-seen, specially if we have a team to work with. On the other hand: **if your code is concurrent and/or reentrant, avoid using global variables or relying on module attributes**. OTOH you will have no problem assigning attributes like that. They will last for the life of your script execution.

This is not the place to chose the **best** alternative. Depending on how you state your problem, you can ask it either on programmers or codereview. You can chose many variants to share state without using global variables in modules, like passing those variables inside a state back and forth across arguments, or learning and using OOP. But, again, this site is no scope for that.

Answer (score 3):

If a module is already imported, subsequent imports to the module uses the cached version of the module. Even if you reference it via different names as in the following case

`import os as a`

`import os as b`

Both refer to the same `os` module that was imported the first time. So it is obvious that the variable assigned to a module will be shared.

You can verify it using the built-in python function `id()`

Comment: Is there a way to force an import from disk and not the cached import?

Comment: Ive never found a use case to have two different copies of the same module. But do a little research on the reload function which claims to refresh the module from the disk if I am not wrong

Comment: I could imagine wanting to do it if you were experimenting with a modified version of a module. But yeah, most of the time, probably not.